# If $a \in \Bbb R$ and $W=\{p \in P_n \mid p(a)=0\}$, show that $W$ is a subspace of $P_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $P_n$ be a vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients and of degree $n$ or less. If $a \in \Bbb R$ and $W=\{p \in P_n \mid p(a)=0\}$, show that $W$ is a subspace of $P_n$.

**Edit:**

**Attempt:**
Denote $0_p$ be the zero polynomial.

1. Since $0_p(a)=0 \in W$, then
   $0_p \in W$ and thus, $W \ne \emptyset$.
2. Let $p,q \in W$. Then,
   $p(a)=0=q(a)$ for some $a \in \Bbb R$.
   Now, $(p+q)(a) = p(a)+q(a)=0+0=0$. Hence, $p+q \in W$.
3. Let $p \in W$. Let $c$ be an arbitrary scalar. Then, $p(a)=0$ for some $a \in \Bbb R$. Now, $(cp)(a)=cp(a)=c0=0$.
   Hence, $cp \in W$.

Thus, $W$ is a subspace of $P_n$.

Am I true?

Comment: For 1. I suggest something like "If $0$ denotes the zero polynomial, then since $0(a)=0$, we have $0 \in W$". Also, you don't need to write *for some $a\in\mathbb R$*, since $a$ is intended to be fixed from the begining. Indeed, we can write $W_a$ instead of $W$, since $W$ depends on $a$.

Comment: Whoa, thats looks nice. Thanks for advice sir.

Comment: Your welcome :)

Comment: @azif00 What about the other two properties? Does it correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @azif00 Noted, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine.

In case you have this tool available, you might also simply observe that $W$ is defined as the kernel of the linear map $P_n\to\Bbb R$, $p\mapsto p(a)$ and therefore a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost right. The train of thought and the important algebraic steps are right. But throughout your argument you refer to "some $a$". That's not  correct. The $a$ is fixed from the start. The space you are interested in might be called $W_a$. It's a different space for each fixed $a$.

Comment: Okay sir. I will edit now.

Comment: @user795084 If you change the proof in your question then my answer won't make sense to someone coming to this site later. If you want to make the correction, do it after the version there, not instead.

Comment: Okay, sir. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Spot on.

You can also condense the latter two properties into one: $$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R; p, q\in W \implies\alpha p + \beta q \in W $$